# equation of projection onto hyperplane

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

Let $P$ be a projection mapping onto the hyperplane trough the origin which is normal to $v$. How do you show that $Px=x-\dfrac{vv^T}{v^Tv}x$

Any intuition?

Comment: Am I having a bad day, or does something seem off about that formula?

Comment: @pjs : Perhaps you're accustomed to seeing it in a different form.  It sometimes gets written as $x - \left(\dfrac{v^T x}{v^T v}\right) v$.  But it's the same thing.  Notice that the numerator in the fraction in this comment is a scalar, but in the posted question the numerator is a square matrix. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelHardy, I am most definitely *not* accustomed to the square matrix version! In fact, you might say I learned something new :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Px$ is just $x$ minus the portion that is parallel to $v$.

$$Px=x-\langle x, \frac{v}{|v|}\rangle \frac{v}{|v|}=x-\frac{x^T v}{v^Tv}v.$$

Answer (score 0):

The vector $x$ can be written as a sum $x = y+z$ where $y$ is a multiple of $v$ and $z$ is orthogonal to $v$.  We want $Px=z$.  The thing that gets divided by the scalar $v^T v$ is a product of three matrices: $(v v^T) x = v(v^T x)$.  This is equal to $v v^T (y+z) = v v^T y + v v^T z$.  Since $z$ is orthogonal to $v$, the second term, $v(v^T z)$ is $0$ since $v^Tz=0$.  Therefore the numerator is $v v^T y$.  Since $y$ is a multiple of $v$, it is $y=cv$ for some scalar $c$, and then we have $v v^T y = c (v v^T) v = c v (v^T v)$.  But $v^T v$ is a scalar that cancels out the denominator, so the fraction is left as $cv$, which is equal to $y$.  Hence $x -\dfrac {v v^T}{v^T v}x = x - y = z$, which is the part of $x$ orthogonal to $v$.

Comment: bthanks for the answer